# Регистрация события Входящий вызов

Tags: android

Хочу реализовать следующее. При работающей программе поступает входящий телефонный звонок, то необходимо завершить некоторые операции.

Нашел что можно реализовать через `broadcast android.intent.action`, но мне не нравится что придется у пользователя запрашивать доп разрешение на это. 
Мне не нужно знать кто звонил и тд. Нужно только понимать что сейчас идет звонок, и что звонок закончился если пользователь не взял трубку. Можно ли сделать не запрашивая доп разрешений?

Answer (score 0):

Вот [статья на habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/company/skbkontur/blog/243063/). В статье есть пункт **Перехватываем звонок**, на код из которого можете ориентироваться. Без разрешения никак не получится т.к. на некоторых устройствах при звонке не происходит даже расфокуса открытого activity.